# lspci not detecting my graphic card

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, vgaswitcheroo, switchable-graphics

I recently purchased a Lenovo g505s, the specifications of which can be found [here](http://www.buyingiq.com/Lenovo-Essential-G505s-59-380146-Laptop-APU-Quad-Core-A10-8GB-1TB-DOS-2.5GB-Graphics-83961).

After setting up Ubuntu 13.04 I tried to install the ATI proprietary drivers. But only my integrated graphics are being detected. Plus there’s an AMD unsupported hardware water mark at the bottom right of my screen(not an issue as long as the system works).

Even lspci -v command does not detect my dedicated graphic card. I tried to check my BIOS but I can't find any option to switch between integrated and dedicated graphics. Currently the graphics option under BIOS is set to switch-able graphics.

Please help me enable my dedicated graphic card.
Here is the output of lspci -v :-

```
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G505s:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Richland [Radeon HD 8650G] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3804
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci

00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f0244000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: f0100000-f01fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f0000000-f00fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0300000-00000000f03fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f0248000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 45
    I/O ports at 3118 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3124 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3110 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3120 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3100 [size=16]
    Memory at f024e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
    Memory at f024d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
    Memory at f024c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
    Memory at f024b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
    Memory at f024a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 397c
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=64

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
    Flags: fast devsel

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3806
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: alx

02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3218
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at f0300000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: are you tried it under windows environment and see if windows program see it to or not?

Comment: nope, ill do that once the download finishes ;) but how will it fix my Ubuntu problem ? cause I don't plan on using windows on my laptop.

Comment: Hi, finally got time to perform a format and dual boot.
Windows detected both my cards and is working in dual graphics mode without any issues !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem sometime back, by.

1) Upgrading to latest kernel and headers :
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/linux-3.8.y.z-review/2013-09-21-raring/

2) And getting the latest ATI proprietary driver :
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

3) Followed by sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade, solved the problem. :)

Comment: Please don't put external links without explanation. The link is dead